Does Cutting Plane method always converge in case of Integer Linear Programming?
I learned that the Cutting plane algorithm using Gromory's cut helps in finally reaching an optimum solution in integer linear programming.
But I also observed that in the simplex tableau, if the simplex has an optimum solution then only we can cut by choosing the tableau constants to make another constraint.
I understand that the constraints do not exclude any integer solution to the problem but what I could not understand is why should the Algorithm converge to a solution? Can't it happen that the new constraint added may or may not decrease the feasible region but does not reach the integer solution as basic solution variables?
I also am unable to understand what will happen to the integer programming if under relaxed conditions the optimization problem is unbounded .
For the sake of simplicity suppose the integer problem is :
$$min\text{ } c'x\\Ax\le b\\x\ge0\\ x\text{'s are all integers} $$ where $A,b,c$ are all constraints.
Hence , its relaxed linear programming will be
$$min\text{ } c'x\\Ax\le b\\x\ge0\\ $$
Can anyone help me to understand why does it converge in the case of Integer Linear Programming?
Thanks in Advance..
